# Visible month change

Tags: swift, uikit, ios16

Does anyone know if there is a way to be notified when a UICalendarView changes the visible month in iOS16? I can’t find any information about this. I would like to be notified so that I can fetch that month’s data and populate the decorations.

Comment: I haven’t used it but my guess is that you need to check the month component in `calendarView(_:decorationFor:)` to see if it has changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, ```calendarView(_:decorationFor:)``` returns a value which makes an async call to get the data from within that function not very useful.

Comment: If you are making an async call (external api?) you probably want to do it ahead of time, so if I move from September to October in the view then you would fetch data for November or something to that affect

Comment: I have tried having the async call get data for a complete year and limiting the UICalendarView to a year. The current month populates quickly, but moving to another month is slow as molasses if I do any kind of check if that date component has an event in my data.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UICalendarViewDelegate` method `didChangeVisibleDateComponents`:

```
func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, didChangeVisibleDateComponentsFrom previousDateComponents: DateComponents) {
    print("didChangeVisibleDateComponents")
}
```

This will be called when you swipe to a different month, tap the previous/next buttons, or use the picker to select a different month/year.